# Problems with the for sentence (shell script)

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop

I don't know if I understand correctly the for sentence in shell script.
This is what I'm trying to do

```
#!/bin/bash

echo Shows the numbers from 1 to 100 and their squares
echo

i=1

for (( i = 1; i <= 100; i++ )); do
    exp= `expr $i \* $i`
    echo "N: $i EXP: $exp"
done
```

And it shows: "Syntax error: Bad for loop variable"

Comment: I don't get the same error: I see `bash: 1: command not found`, `bash: 4: command not found`, `bash: 9: command not found`, etc, up to `10000: command not found` -- what version of bash are you running?

Comment: ...now, you *do* need to get rid of the space in the `exp=` assignment, or, better, replace that with native math: `exp=$(( i * i ))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you running this script?

Are you using `/bin/sh scriptfile.sh` instead of `/bin/bash scriptfile.sh` or `/path/to/scriptfile.sh`?

Because that looks like a `dash` error because dash doesn't support the arithmetic for loop syntax.

Comment: What do you mean? I'm executing this in my terminal like "sh scripfile.sh"

Comment: Yes, `sh` is not `bash`. Your script is using `bash`/etc. features. Try `bash scriptfile.sh` and it should work. As will `./scriptfile.sh` (etc.) once you give your script executable permissions (because of your `#!/bin/bash` shebang line at the top).

Comment: Oh right! I din't noticed that. It works now! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you have made the script executable: `chmod u+x script.sh` and you are calling it as:

```
$ ./script.sh
```

the script will load bash as the interpreter of the script.
If you are using something like: `sh script.sh` then it might be that your used shell is something else, like dash, ksh, zsh or some other set as the shell connected to the file link /bin/sh.

Please check Bash is the executing shell. If still in problems:

An space after the `=` is interpreted by the shell as a new word, which will be executed.
Therefore, trying to execute a command named `4, 9 or 16, etc.` will trigger an `command not found` error.

This will work (no need to use `i=1` as it is set at the for start):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "Shows the numbers from 1 to 100 and their squares"
echo
for (( i=1; i<=100; i++ )); do
    exp=`expr $i \* $i`
    echo "N: $i EXP: $exp"
done
```

But really, in bash, this will be more idiomatic:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
echo -e "Shows the numbers from 1 to 100 and their squares\n"
for ((i=1; i<=100; i++)); do
    echo "N: $i EXP: $(( i**2 ))"
done
```

Comment: I disagree that `{1..10}` is more idiomatic; it's often avoided (I'd argue wisely) because of its inability to use expansion results for the start/end values.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy What I meant to be more idiomatic is the `$(( i**2 ))`. But I am happy to agree with you about the `{1..10}`. Changed already.